# Cumulative sum per group in tidyverse R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, cumulative-sum

I have paneldata, i.e. repeated observations per household. A unit (household) is measured through time and exhibits a characteric (e.g. `variable`). I can calculate a group sum per year with `group_by(id, year)`. How can I have a cummulative sum over time as in the `goal` column? I need the result to preserve 10 rows in this example, i.e. not collapse data to the years. How can I pick just one group-sum per year per unit to sum up?

```
set.seed(1234)
data <- data.frame(id = rep(100, 10),
                   year = c(rep(2022, 5), rep(2023, 5)),
                   variable = rbinom(10, 1, 0.5))

library(tidyverse)

data <- data %>% 
  group_by(id, year) %>% 
  mutate(group_sum_per_year = sum(variable)) 

data$goal <- c(4,4,4,4,4,7,7,7,7,7)

data

# A tibble: 10 × 5
# Groups:   id, year [2]
      id  year variable group_sum_per_year  goal
   <dbl> <dbl>    <int>              <int> <dbl>
 1   100  2022        0                  4     4
 2   100  2022        1                  4     4
 3   100  2022        1                  4     4
 4   100  2022        1                  4     4
 5   100  2022        1                  4     4
 6   100  2023        1                  3     7
 7   100  2023        0                  3     7
 8   100  2023        0                  3     7
 9   100  2023        1                  3     7
10   100  2023        1                  3     7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first create a tempory column `hlp` which is equal to `group_sum_per_year` for only the first entry per group.

Then you could group by `id` and use cumsum on `hlp`:

```
data %>% 
  group_by(id, year) %>% 
  mutate(group_sum_per_year = sum(variable)) %>% 
  mutate(hlp = if_else(1:n() == 1, group_sum_per_year, 0)) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(goal = cumsum(hlp))

# A tibble: 10 × 6
# Groups:   id [1]
      id  year variable group_sum_per_year   hlp  goal
   <dbl> <dbl>    <int>              <int> <dbl> <dbl>
 1   100  2022        0                  4     4     4
 2   100  2022        1                  4     0     4
 3   100  2022        1                  4     0     4
 4   100  2022        1                  4     0     4
 5   100  2022        1                  4     0     4
 6   100  2023        1                  3     3     7
 7   100  2023        0                  3     0     7
 8   100  2023        0                  3     0     7
 9   100  2023        1                  3     0     7
10   100  2023        1                  3     0     7
```

Answer (score 1):

A more intuitive approach is to:

- use `summarise` instead of `mutate`
- merge with the original dataframe using `right_join`

```r
data %>% 
  group_by(id, year) %>% 
  summarise(group_sum_per_year = sum(variable)) %>% # Note the use of `summarise` here
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(goal = cumsum(group_sum_per_year)) %>% 
  right_join(data)
```

Comment: Good idea. I was not aware that the pipe memorizes `data` that can be used at the end of pipe in a `right_join`. I usually store results from a `summarise` in another df and `left_join` afterwards.